# How to Clear Local IIS server Error?

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-3.0

This is my connection string-code

in my webconfig file getting this error.when iam connection local database.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) .anyone know fine this error

Comment: Can you please show us your connection string ?

Comment: @gkrishy-<add name="sqlcon" connectionString="Data Source=ARABSWELL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=bedoonzaytdb;Integrated Security=sspi;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> this my connection string can anyone can let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding this line in your connection string that is,

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```

SO your connection string will seem like this,

```
<add name="sqlcon" connectionString="Data Source=ARABSWELL\SQLEXPRESS;
 Initial Catalog=bedoonzaytdb;Integrated Security=sspi;
 Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=True;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: @gkrishy-when im given "TrustServerCertificate=True" im getting this error -Cannot open database "bedoonzaytdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ARABSWELL\IUSR_ARABSWELL'.but the database connection was correct can anyone know let me find this one

Comment: You should not change your question like this. Please post it as other one. Because my answer is entirely different from your question now. You got an answer for your first question. So please mark it as answer and post this new question as new question. I will guide you over there

Comment: -s cleared previous error  after that comming this error new error.Cannot open database "bedoonzaytdb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'ARABSWELL\IUSR_ARABSWELL

Comment: Replace this new question with your old one. And post this new question as new one. So you will get help from all others. If you get satisfy with my answer for your question, then mark it as an answer. Please change this question with old one.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have answered your new question. Follow the instructions which i mentioned over there. And i hope this answer for this question has been rectified your problem. So please mark it as answer. So others may use of it.